# deploying an nginx/rails/node app onto EC2

Tags: deployment, amazon-ec2, nginx, capistrano

## Basic Problem

- I have an app I'm building, and was hoping to get some help deploying it to EC2
- I've been told I should use capistrano
- What are my next steps?

### About the App

- simple rails app (3.1.1)
- simple node app (0.4.2)
- redis to communicate between rails and node (2.0.4)
- nginx to reverse proxy both rails and node (1.0.6)
- database is currently sqlite (but will probably upgrade to mysql or mongo in the near future)
- an nginx.conf file is as follows:

  ```
  worker_processes  1;

  events {
      worker_connections  1024;
  }

  http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
      }

      location /events/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_read_timeout 1000s;
      }
    }
  }
  ```

### About the EC2 instance

- ec2-12-34-56-789.compute-1.amazonaws.com
- Basic 64 bit Amazon Linux t1.micro (until I get everything working, then I'll find some other place to deploy; possibly EC2, possibly rackspace, possibly something completely different)

### About my deploying platform

- OSX 10.6.8
- Have the following contents stored in ~/.ec2/   (probably needs to be moved to get capistrano to work)

  ```
  cert-123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0.pem
  pk-123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0.pem
  ec2-keypair
  ```
- Currently have the following deploy.rb (but it's not working)

  ```
  set :application, "clashcentral"
  set :repository,  "git@github.com:HairyMezican/GameLobby.git"
  set :branch, "master"
  set :repository_cache, "git_cache"
  set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
  set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }

  set :scm, :git
  ssh_options[:keys] = [File.join(ENV["HOME"], ".ec2", "ec2-keypair")] 

  role :web, "ec2-12-34-56-789.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
  role :app, "ec2-12-34-56-789.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
  role :db,  "ec2-12-34-56-789.compute-1.amazonaws.com", :primary => true
  ```

#### errors

- The original error I was getting was `connection failed for: ec2-12-34-56-789.compute-1.amazonaws.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Empty)`
- The current error I am getting, when I added in the line `set :user, "ec2-user"` is `failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /u/apps/clashcentral/shared/git_cache ]; then cd /u/apps/clashcentral/shared/git_cache && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard cdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q  git@github.com:HairyMezican/GameLobby.git /u/apps/clashcentral/shared/git_cache && cd /u/apps/clashcentral/shared/git_cache && git checkout -q -b deploy cdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd; fi'" on ec2-12-34-56-789.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Currently, when I run 'cap deploy' or 'cap deploy:setup', I get told, "connection failed for: ec2-12-34-56-789.compute-1.amazonaws.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Empty)"

Comment: Can you ssh to the server directly?

Comment: yes; "ssh -i ~/.ec2/ec2-keypair ec2-user@ec2-12-34-56-789.compute-1.amazonaws.com" gets me into the SSH screen on my instance

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing the actual error message into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add:

```
set :user, "ec2-user"
```

to your `deploy.rb` file, as seen here: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Capistrano#Automate_Deployment_with_Capistrano_.28.22capify.22.29

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting a different error when I put that in.  I guess that's progress

Comment: Wow, that `cdcdcd..` sure is surprising. I can't make heads or tails of that.

Comment: The cdcd stuff is just me redacting information. Would having the actual information that goes there be more useful?

Comment: That makes me feel better :) but no, it wouldn't help _me_ any. Good luck. :)